# No such file to load --openssl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I Am using ruby 1.9.2 (without rvm) and rails 3.0.0 on Ubuntu..when i am trying to run the server following error is coming:
No such file to load --openssl...
I am new to ruby on rails so plz help me out...

Comment: Did you install ruby from source or through the ubuntu packages?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, but the trick is to install the following before ruby:

```
$ install build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline5-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install the following Debian/Ubuntu packages before building Ruby or Gem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 libreadline5-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

If you built Ruby or Gem without some of those packages installed, you'll need to rebuild them.

Then, the following will fix the `No such file to load -- openssl` error. Go to the Ruby source directory, e.g. `ruby-1.9.2-p180/`.

```
$ cd ext/openssl
$ make
$ sudo make install
```